# Build and export a Flutter app as real app from VS CODE

Tags: android, ios, flutter

How we can build and install a flutter app form VS code, lot of people i see they develop from vs code and build from android studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build your app from vs code, lot of people I see they develop from vs code and build from android studio, there is no need of it, you can build and your flutter app from vs code,
just follow these steps

1 - (integrated terminal)

```
//run this command in your vs code integrated terminal

 # flutter build appbundle
```

[image]

after that run this command

```
flutter build apk --split-per-abi
```

[image]

it will build your apk file after that connect your phone or launch emulator that you want to install your app,
after that type this command

```
flutter install
```

[image]

after that choose your device to install
Woha! it's ready!!

Answer (score 0):

(The accepted answer is partially helpfull.)

Build and install APK for all architectures:

```bash
flutter build apk 
flutter install --device-id <YOUR-DEVICE-ID>
```

Build and install APK for a specific architecture:

```bash
flutter build apk -split-per-abi

# check output from last command for paths

flutter install 
  --device-id <YOUR-DEVICE-ID> 
  --use-application-binary=<APK-PATH>
```

Display all available device IDs by running:

`flutter install`